# Stack Overflow memory leak

Tags: bug

Chrome latest. If I leave my computer open with a lot of Stack Overflow tabs:

[image: stackoverflowmemoryleak]

Computer/laptop running mostly 24/7 for 5 days per week. Did not switch into power saving at night because of CPU usage.

It happened a few times. When I check task list in Chrome it's only Stack Overflow tabs causing the CPU and memory problem.

I have always about 50 tabs open. When I leave the desk the laptop switch in about an hour in to power save normally.

I am an experienced Chrome user since day 1 for about ten years and I never saw this behaviour before.

Comment: You may need to fill a bug report with Google if you think Chrome has a memory leak.

Comment: I always have about 50-100 tabs open on a computer running 24/7 for 5 days a week. Only Stackoverflow is causing this

Comment: [On Chrome, latest](https://imgur.com/a/b2kxn). Problem is on your end. Fans on this machine run like crazy when I open Civ VI instead of SO...

Comment: Have you checked extensions/userscripts?

Comment: @Rob but Iam only see this behaviour with Stackoverflow tabs, not the other 50 open for a long period 3-5 days.. I switch my computer off only once a week

Comment: Since it only happens to you, and we are 99% sure the problem is on your end... what do you want us to do about it? You need tech-support, not a discussion in meta.

Comment: @yivi using Chrome almost for 10 years, with 50-100 tabs daily open, for 24/7-5 to seven days, I never saw this behaviour before and after a few times, I saw it only happens to Stackoverflow tabs explicit not to any other. That's why I included an image...
But as you are 'We' the experts, you probably never heart about major website's injecting virus, running mining or any other problems.... Because major website's never fail. I never said it was caused by Stackoverflow. Thanks for your advice that it can never be an Stackoverflow problem,. I will close the Stackoverflow tabs so no problem.

Comment: Great to know that your problem was solved. Have a wonderful day.

Comment: There could be a legitimate issue, but with the information you've provided it's impossible to tell. Perhaps tell us whether or not you run an ad blocker, if it's specific pages or all pages, how long the tabs have to be open to experience this issue. Maybe take a memory dump and do some analysis to see if you can pin-point the source of the issue.

Comment: @Stijn your right. I should have explained the conditions. Error from my part

Comment: So, you don't have _any_ extensions or plugins? That's still not clear.

Comment: @Cerbus I do have extensions, but because of the behaviour only experienced with open Stackoverflow tabs, so it would be an combination with Stackoverflow, I never experienced this with other tabs. I always have about 50 open and especially  have 32GB because tabs use a lot of memory.
I will try with a clean build to see if it's still a problem.

Comment: 'Chrome' and 'memory leak' in the same post.  Who would have believed it?

Comment: 24/7 for 5 days a week...WAT? How do you fit the other two days in there? Time travel?

Answer (score -9):

Stack Overflow barely used any memory for me. Roughly a factor 50 lower than you're reporting.

Considering you're using `301.9%` of your available CPU, and the ***massive*** memory usage of your chrome tabs, I think you may have a virus.

Run a couple of scans, disable all plugins in your browser, or even re-install the browser. It's extremely unlikely that this is an issue on Stack Overflow's end.

Comment: I'm not sure - that "Take the 2018 Developer Survey today" banner looks like it could really swallow up some resources :p

Comment: I always have about 50-100 tabs open on a computer running 24/7 for 5 days a week. Only Stackoverflow is causing this

Comment: A virus can target specific pages you're visiting. If you've got an infection that injects content into a page... It wouldn't be the first time I've seen one specifically target sites like SO. Please, run a scan. better safe than sorry.

Comment: That sure was a fast virus scan you just ran to verify that. And 100% certain too! Guess I need to switch my AV.