# Why do stale Stack Overflow tabs use so many resources?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, performance, web-sockets

I have a tendency to leave a lot of browser tabs open. I just noticed in Chrome Task Manager that the tabs on Stack Overflow that I haven't looked at in a while are over 2 GB memory and 100% CPU. If I go to the tab and refresh things go back to under 100 MB and 0%. Why is that?

It's possible that some or all of these tabs haven't been open since I last rebooted Chrome, if that makes a difference. I don't run any ad blockers, and the only non-Google extension installed is Evernote Web Clipper.

The tabs on Stack Overflow are the only ones that have this problem. I have plenty of other unused tabs to other sites, and those are just fine.

[This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361742/stackoverflow-memory-leak) appears to have the same problem, but the only explanation offered (a virus) seems extremely unlikely. This is a corporate system with mandatory anti-virus installed.

Comment: "This is a corporate system with mandatory anti-virus installed." I think you overestimate the fallibility of anti-virus software...sure, it's possible that something else is going on, but having anti-virus software installed doesn't automatically rule out malware on your computer as the problem, it just lowers the odds.

Comment: @Servy I did say unlikely, not impossible. But why would it only attack StackOverflow?

Comment: As a way of avoiding detection, possibly.  It's *is* the kind of thing that malware will do.

Comment: I've noticed this before mainly with chrome on pages with websockets on machines with a meager amount of ram and a small CPU. If you're using a modern computer then you should have at least 32gb of ram and at least a 2.8 ghz 8 core processor, which should eliminate any such issue.

Comment: @TinyGiant yes this is a nicely provisioned PC, I wouldn't even have noticed if I hadn't gone to Chrome Task Manager for other reasons.

Comment: Have you tested this on another machine? I did recently switch from Chrome to Firefox so I can’t say I have recent knowledge but I certainly never experienced Stack Overflow being more greedy than other sites, just that Chrome always had issues with a lot of open tabs.

Comment: seems fine on my dual core, though i have this extension that suspends inactive tabs

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have the same habits at home, so I'll check there in an hour or two. That PC is much less capable than this one though.

Comment: My oldest Chrome tab on one machine (open about 3 days) is 900K; on another (open about 2 weeks) is a bit over 2GB. Chrome is a pig.

Comment: If you have the tab still up, what does your dev console look like? Mine just had websocket connection failures.

Comment: @JoeyZero I don't do browser debugging so I don't know how to get to dev console. I did leave one tab untouched so I could answer questions like yours.

Comment: Same issue noticed yesterday. 2GB of memory being used by a Stack Overflow tab opened a few days ago but left open.
PC is Windows 10, 3.5GHZ 6 core, 32GB memory running Chrome Version 63.0.3239.132

 Links to Chrome Task Manager & Console:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SX8nx.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYFaY.jpg

Comment: One problem is that  AV sofware does not recognise Chrome as malware:)

Comment: @MarkRansom Right clicking anywhere on the stack overflow page and hit Inspect which should launch the dev tools. Then just click on the Console tab.
or
Press Command+Option+I (Mac) or Control+Shift+I (Windows, Linux).

Comment: @JoeyZero thanks. "full.en.js?v=1c4429b3ea52:1 WebSocket connection to 'wss://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
n @ full.en.js?v=1c4429b3ea52:1
2full.en.js?v=1c4429b3ea52:1 WebSocket connection to 'wss://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/' failed: WebSocket opening handshake timed out"

Comment: @MarkRansom yea seems very similar to my console errors.

Comment: @MartijnPieters this is odd, at home the task manager doesn't even show half my tabs. None of the inactive StackOverflow tabs are in the list.

Comment: I've never had an issue with it and I've got SO tabs that have been open for weeks. Think of this as an excellent opportunity to get more intimate knowledge of the Chrome devtools and see if you can hunt down what's causing it :) There's some really good tools available. I'd look for it but I don't have a leak in my version so there's nothing to look for.

Comment: I really like [The Great Suspender](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/the-great-suspender/klbibkeccnjlkjkiokjodocebajanakg?hl=en).  It's an addon that *fully* unloads tabs you haven't used for a while (if there's no unsaved textboxes, etc.).  On my old computer, it made my usage-pattern of leaving tons of tabs open to get back to later possible.  On my current computer, I still use it because I hate browser tabs wasting CPU time / memory bandwidth / power, especially when I'm trying to benchmark something.  My last reboot was after about 4 months of uptime with the same chrome open.

Comment: I haven't generally had a problem with SO tabs, though.  I have a couple that have been open for days (with partially-typed answers or edits), and none of them are over 150MiB, and none are using any CPU according to chrome's task manager.

Comment: Every couple/few days I encounter an issue that appears identical to this. One Chrome tab to SO, or multiple SO tabs, will get to 2GB of RAM usage and start using 100% CPU (on the one it's running). This can be quite annoying when it happens on multiple tab groups, each taking 100% of a CPU, potentially up to all CPUs. However, I have quite a number of userscripts running, so I haven't yet attempted to localize it down to a user script, or the page. From time to time, I've seen tabs which are heading in that direction (large RAM usage), & reloaded to resolve the issue early. Win10x64 32GB RAM.

Comment: @Servy did you mean "underestimate"?

Comment: @MarkRansom Same behavior at home? Is there an IPS at work that might see the continual traffic from all your SO tabs as a threat; and preventing those connections? Talk to your security engineer, check logs for your IP.

Comment: It's probably the bitcoin mining script which triggers when the tab is idle. Nothing to worry about, its normal.

Comment: I've had the Evernote Web Clipper do some strange things in the past (though not with SO.) Can you reproduce the problem with it disabled?

Comment: @Vatev monero is more efficient with cpu mining, if anything, it would be that.

Comment: @Mafii shht, don't tell them that, they are gonna drive the difficulty up.

Comment: I sometimes see similar behavior in Firefox on Linux.  It seems usually to happen when I've left two or more tabs open on SO over the weekend.  When I return, Firefox is nearly inoperable, but closing the SO tabs (not easy in that state) or killing and restarting Firefox clears everything up.  But I haven't figured out an exact recipe for reproducing the behavior reliably.

Comment: @MattGibson I just tried disabling it, we'll see if it makes a difference. None of the tabs I refreshed on Friday are misbehaving today, but the one I left alone is still at 100% CPU and is now up to 2.7TB memory.

Comment: @Vatev I had the bitcoin thought too, but didn't consider it seriously.

Comment: @MarkRansom , what kind of computer are you running that allows 2.7TB of memory usage? :-)

Comment: @JoeyZero Ha, of course I meant 2.7GB. My first computer had 64K of RAM, and I was lucky to have it - a person shouldn't have to go through that many orders of magnitude in their lifetime.

Comment: This is probably worth reporting as a bug to the chrome(ium) team, if there's something specific about SO's use of websockets that is making chrome leak memory.

Comment: I'd suggest trying to reproduce this problem in an Incognito Window with no extensions enabled. If the problem still occurs, take a heap snapshot and post it here: DevTools -> Memory -> Take snapshot. If CPU usage is high, a performance profile would also be good: DevTools -> Performance -> Record

Comment: This isn't a Chrome issue, Edge and Firefox do exactly the same.  It used to happen on my old Windows 7 machine, and my Windows 10 laptop.  It was also happening in Edge on my brand-new machine, with next to nothing installed on it yet, and still happens now in both Edge and Chrome.  Other tabs use < 300 MB at most, and it's all sites within the Stack family that it applies to.  It's most definitely not virus, malware or extension-related.  It doesn't really matter, as closing the tab returns the memory with almost immediate effect, but it's definitely caused by Stack Exchange sites themselves

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I remember this (one would hope, given I commented on it...) - for a few weeks, leaving SO tabs open would often - but not always - gradually consume memory and CPU until eventually crashing the browser (or tab group).

Brian Ross, myself and a few others spent some time digging into it, and narrowed it down to a badly-written script served as part of Google's ad platform. That's was frustrating, as there's no easy way to fix something like that (short of blocking ads).

...And then the problem went away. Presumably Google fixed it; in any case, I haven't seen this happen in many months now, so marking it status-norepro to signify that we haven't fixed anything and are presumably still susceptible to such problems in the future, but hopefully won't actually suffer from them again.

So, thanks for the report & sorry for the inconvenience; if nothing else, this is a good reminder that ad platforms continue to be the achilles heel of the Internet.

Comment: I haven't seen it in a long time either. I just double-checked to make sure I hadn't missed it. Thanks for reporting back!

Comment: @Shog9 I used to have this happening a lot on my Windows laptop and always suspected it was ad related. Then I started using The Great Suspender - a godsend. Switched to a Mac a few months back and I thought the problem was gone, but it happened today. It's very frustrating.

Comment: ehh.. unfortunately those things are still happening.. time after time i found some tab running 100% it always turns out the reason is poorly written ads, ad frames etc.. anyway, thank you for looking into this !